When posting on django website it posts it to a different page
Making a website that has a forum for text posts and a greenhouse page for images, when I try to post on the forum page it posts it to the greenhouse page, and when i try to add a comment on a post in the forum page I get:
PlantPost matching query does not exist.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/greenhouse/create_comment/1/
Django Version: 5.0.4
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
PlantPost matching query does not exist.
Exception Location: C:\Users\hurle\OneDrive\Documents\Desktop\profile_env\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py, line 649, in get
Raised during:  greenhouse.views.create_comment
Python Executable:  C:\Users\hurle\OneDrive\Documents\Desktop\profile_env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.12.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\hurle\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Desktop\\bloomhub4',
 'C:\\Users\\hurle\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python312.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\hurle\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\hurle\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib',
 'C:\\Users\\hurle\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312',
 'C:\\Users\\hurle\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Desktop\\profile_env',
 'C:\\Users\\hurle\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Desktop\\profile_env\\Lib\\site-packages']

forum create_comment.html
{% extends "home.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h2>Add Comment</h2>
<form action="{% url 'forum:create_comment' post.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}```
**forum create_post.html**
```{% extends "home.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h2>Create Post</h2>
<form action="{% url 'create_post' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}

forum models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="forum_images/", null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="forum_comments")

forum views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Post, Comment
from .forms import PostForm, CommentForm

def forum(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    comment_form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, "forum.html", {"posts": posts, "comment_form": comment_form})

def create_post(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect("forum")
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, "create_post.html", {"form": form})

def create_comment(request, post_id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect("forum")
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, "create_comment.html", {"form": form, "post": post})

urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.forum, name="forum"),
    path("create_post/", views.create_post, name="create_post"),
    path("create_comment/<int:post_id>/", views.create_comment, name="create_comment"),
    
]

I want to be able to make posts on the forum page, the create_post.html and  create_comment.html for both apps are under the same name.

It seems the url is not found in the below line of code:
<form action="{% url 'forum:create_comment' post.id %}" method="post">

In urls.py, I do not find the above url format, that might be the reason why its giving error when you try to post any comment on forum page.
You will have to add a separate path in urls.py to post a comment on forum page as you did here below:
 path("create_comment/<int:post_id>/", views.create_comment, name="create_comment"),

